# Logarithm rules in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I have trouble with basic rules when it comes to logarithm counting in complex analysis, in my book we use $\mathrm{Log}(2+i)$ when it is single-valued and $\log(2+i)$ when it is multivalued. Apparently $\log(z_1z_2) = \log(z_1) + \log(z_2)$ (notice multivalued). But the same thing does not work when it is multivalued, that means $\mathrm{Log}(z_1z_2)$ is NOT $\mathrm{Log}(z_1) + \mathrm{Log}(z_2)$. Is there anybody who can describe to me why it is like this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the good old rule of $\log(ab)=\log(a)+\log(b)$ does not hold in the standard sense for complex numbers. The single valued Log is typically defined as
$$ {\rm Log} (r e^{i\phi}) = \log(r) + i \phi $$
for $r>0$ and $\phi\in (-\pi,\pi]$. But note this implies that the argument of any complex ${\rm Log} (z)$ is never larger than $\pi$ in absolute value. Therefore, the rule 
$${\rm Log} (z^p)= p {\rm Log}(z) = p\log (r) + i p \phi $$ for non-real $z$ MUST fail for $p$ large. Now one way to repair is to say that the argument is only defined up to integer multiples of $2\pi$. With that definition the multiplication rule works again but you have to settle for an argument which is only defined mod $2\pi$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that explaination, I do have another question if that's okay, my book is talking about something that looks like a "weird" L, for example L(z) = Log(z) + i arg(z). I hope you understand what "weird L" I mean....

Comment: Not quite. Is Log$(z)$ here the one stated earlier which already has a term $i$ arg$(z)$ ?  And what are the values of arg?

Comment: It actually pisses me off that I cannot give a description that is better than the one I've given, there is not explanation in the book about this sign except that its looking like a "weird L"... They use it in the chapter of "The logarithmic function"

Comment: But there is no abs sign inside the Log? (which would make sense then). You may by the way look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm

Comment: whatever the (and how many) branch you consider, the rule becomes $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{C}^*, \exists n \in \mathbb{Z}, \ \log(ab) = \log(a)+\log(b)+ 2i \pi n$  @A.Maine